# Why does this throw an exception in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Why does the following  code throw an 'Unspecified error' (on the `appendChild` line) in Internet Explorer 11 which I click the button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function go() {
          var popUp = window.open('about:blank');
          popUp.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="go()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does ie11 block popups? I asked because while chrome blocks popup i see error.

Comment: The code works in Chrome and Firefox if you disable pop up blocking for the domain.

Comment: The script tag is not properly closed (missing >)

Comment: @AlexV that was a typo in the question. Thanks for letting me know. The question still stands.

Comment: @farhatmihalko Pop up blocking is not the issue. A JavaScript error is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the document of the current page to create the div, try using the document from the popup window

```
popUp.document.body.appendChild(popUp.document.createElement('div'));
```

Comment: Why will this make a difference? In the real code, I want to use an element created by the opener document.

Comment: It does, well for IE. See http://jsfiddle.net/mc31xue6/ . if you want to use an element from the opener document use [`importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode)

Comment: Using `importNode` throws another exception. I may open another question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Popup blockers will typically only allow `window.open` if used during the processing of a user event (like a click). That might be causing the problem if you have popups blocked.

You need to call window.open from an event initiated by the user, e.g. clicking on a link, and that link needs to have `target="_blank"`. Otherwise, Chrome and Firefox will block the popup.

Also, the error is triggered because `popUp` is not checked for `null` before attempting to append the div to it. If there's no popup, you can't append an element to it.

(I forgot this bit and Musa made me remember, so thanks) IE will block appending any element created in a different window context from the window context that the element is being appending to. So, instead of creating the DIV node using the current document, you need to create it using the popUp's context.

Summing it all up, this is how it would look the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script>
        function go() 
        {
            var popUp = window.open('about:blank');
            try 
            {
                // Make sure you have a body document when creating the new window....
                popUp.document.write("<html><head><title></title></head><body></body>");
                popUp.document.body.appendChild(popUp.document.createElement('div'));
            }
            catch(e)
            { 
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="go()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, I simplified the problem down to this. Even with a button it throws. I will add a button to the question.

Comment: That would give you `Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference`